# Disable the virtualization of Ag Grid during Cypress tests for a Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, cypress, ag-grid, virtualization

How could I disable the virtualization of Ag Grid during Cypress tests for a Vue.js application?

Since the Ag Grid does not draw everything at once I have to simulate scrolling to verify the data in grid, the grid behavior, etc. That makes my Cypress/Mocha tests cumbersome.

While if I would be able to set [the suppressColumnVirtualisation and the suppressRowVirtualisation](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/) to true for all the Ag Grid instances before the tests are run I would have much simpler and leaner code in tests. I did some research online but found nothing about it and was hoping if maybe someone knows how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to switch virtualization off when Cypress is running the browser (i.e the window).

```js
<template>
  <div style="height: 100%">
    <div style="height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <ag-grid-vue
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        @grid-ready="onGridReady"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        :suppressColumnVirtualisation="suppressVirtualisation"
        :suppressRowVirtualisation="suppressVirtualisation"
        :rowData="rowData">
      </ag-grid-vue>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      columnDefs: [..],
      ...
      suppressVirtualisation: false   // want virtualization on in the real world
    };
  },
  created() {                      
    if (window.Cypress) {                  // check if Cypress has control
      this.suppressVirtualisation = true   // turn off virtualization
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way I could pass data from Cypress somehow more deterministically? I tried adding the root level hook: `before(() => { window.e2eTestIsRunning = true; });`, but inside the application accessing the `window.e2eTestIsRunning` gives `undefined`. I assume these are two different window instances.

Comment: I think you would use `window:before:load` event [ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Event-Types) - says "Listen for window:before:load events and modify the window before any of your app code runs".

Comment: But in the app checking `window.Cypress` is the same thing - if an e2e test is not running `window.Cypress` will be undefined (false).